# Пишу клиент-серверное приложение, от сервера клиенту сообщение приходит, а от клиента серверу не приходит

Tags: java, сервер, исключения, клиент-сервер, клиент

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение, от сервера клиенту сообщение приходит, а от клиента серверу не приходит. Причём не выводится никакой ошибки,
просто программа выводит только одну строку (сообщение для клаиента)

```
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class CleentServer {


    public static class Cleent {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Cleent().reception();
            new Cleent().sending();
        }
       public void sending(){
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                writer.println("Сообщение для сервера");
                writer.close();
            } catch (IIOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       }
        public void reception(){
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String messeg = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(messeg);//вывод на экран сообщения от сервера
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Server().sending();
            new Server().reception();
        }  public void sending(){
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); //блокирует сокет до тех пор
                    //пока нет связи с клеентом
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());//отправляет
                    //сообщение клеенту
                    writer.println("Сообщение для клеента");
                    writer.close();//закрывает сокет
                }
            }catch (IIOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void reception(){
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket2 = new ServerSocket(5000);

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket2.accept(); //блокирует сокет до тех пор
                    //пока нет связи с клеентом
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String messege = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(messege);
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }


            } 
            }


        }
```

Comment: Вот честно, не пойму, как у вас в 1 потоке main работает и сервер и клеент. Или вы дважды запускаете приложение? Или вы это привели 2 разных класса, которые запускаете также в 2 окна? и, если у вас идет блокировка сокета сервера, как может быть доставлено ему сообщение, если он заблокирован?

Comment: @ Dred, запускаю поочерёдно, сначала сервер, затем клиент
По поводу блокировки были догадки, но если её просто убрать, всё вообще перестаёт работать

Comment: Вы создаёте два сервера на одном и том же порте. Зачем вообще вы создаёте два разных сокета для отправки и принятия сообщений? С обеими этими задачами прекрасно справляется один сокет.

Comment: @ Имя Фамилия, пробовал, не получилось, решил разбить на два метода, но результат остался тем же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаёте два разных сервера на одном и том же порте. Естественно, что один из них не работает.
Вдобавок, вы создаёте по одному сокету у клиента и сервера для передачи и принятия сообщения. С обеими этими задачами справляется один сокет.
Чтобы принимать и отправлять сообщения, у сервера и у клиента нужно создать `Reader` и `Writer`. Тут существуют вариации c `PrintWriter`, `BufferedWriter`, а также с `BufferedReader`, `Scanner` и т.д.

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

Правильный код для клиента и сервера будет выглядеть так. В данном примере используется [`try с ресурсами`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) для автозакрытия сокетов и потоков вывода и ввода.

**Client**

```java
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {
            out.write("Сообщение для сервера\n");
            out.flush(); // \n и flush() нужны, чтобы BufferedReader на стороне сервера смог принять сообщение
            String serverMessage = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(serverMessage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

```java
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
             Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
             BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))) {
            String clientMessage = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(clientMessage);
            out.write("Сообщение для клиента\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Результат в консоли клиента:**
`Сообщение для клиента`

**Результат в консоли сервера:**
`Сообщение для сервера`

[Статья про сокеты](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/654-klassih-socket-i-serversocket-ili-allo-server-tih-menja-slihshishjh)

Comment: почему-то всё равно приходит только "сообщение для клиента"

Comment: @SemenovNilolay странно. Вы точно правильно всё делаете?

Comment: @ Имя Фамилия, я создал новый проект и скопировал туда Ваш код

Comment: @SemenovNilolay ну а потом запустили сервер, запустили клиент. У вас точно не стоит на этом порте ранее написанный сервер? Этот код не может не работать.

Comment: @ Имя Фамилия, я, возможно, понимаю не правильно, но получается, я должен убрать номер этого порта из прошлого проекта, чтобы этот заработал?

Comment: @НиколайСеменов а у вас прошлый сервер ещё работает? К одному порту может подключиться только один сервер.

Comment: @Имя Фамилия, нет, номер порта указан в программном коде прошлого сервера, но он не запущен

Comment: @НиколайСеменов если он не запущен, то он и не может ни на что влиять. Вы запустили сервер из моего ответа? Он заработал? Потом запускаете клиент из моего ответа, после этого в консолях сервера и клиента должны будут вывестись сообщения. Не понимаю, в чём проблема. Этот код работает у меня, и у автора статьи аналогичный код работает.

Comment: @НиколайСеменов в коде, который я выложил, сообщение для клиента приходит после того, как должно вывестись в консоль сообщение для сервера. Как у вас сообщение для клиента приходит, а для сервера - нет? Вы точно правильно мой код скопировали?

Comment: @ Имя Фамилия, я скопировал Ваш код в Intelij IDEA, после чего запустил сначала сервер, затем клиент

Comment: @НиколайСеменов попробуйте сменить порт и запустите ещё раз. Может быть, у вас там что-то запущено всё-таки. Смените, например, на 9999.

Comment: @ Имя Фамилия, заработало, спасибо!